# Problems with Google API Client Library for PHP

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google's API Client Library for PHP with my app, to authenticate whether certain tokes are authentic or no.

As per their instructions, there are 2 methods to do this.
First is using composer, which I did not go by, and second, which is to download the zip file from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/ and move it somewhere in your server; which I did. So far, so good.

Then, as per Google,

```
Uncompress the zip file you download, and include the autoloader in your project:

require_once '/path/to/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
```

The main reason to do this, is to run the below code for the check.

```
// Get $id_token via HTTPS POST.
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
  $userid = $payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //$domain = $payload['hd'];
} else {
  // Invalid ID token
}
```

However, I get a fatal error from the following line:

```
require_once 'require_once '/var/www/html/various/google-api-php-client-2.1.1/vendor/autoload.php';
```

The error using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` is:

```
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  require_once(/var/www/html/various/google-api-php-client-2.1.1/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/var/www/html/php/insert.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
    <br />
<pre>
    &lt;b&gt;Fatal error&lt;/b&gt;:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/various/google-api-php-client-2.1.1/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in &lt;b&gt;/var/www/html/php/insert.php&lt;/b&gt; on line &lt;b&gt;6&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
</pre>
```

Currntly, my insert.php code is:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include_once ('/var/www/db/connection.php');
require_once '/var/www/html/various/google-api-php-client-2.1.1/vendor/autoload.php';

$value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 
?>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: There should be additional errors before the Fatal error that will explain why, specifically, PHP could not open that file. For example, if the file doesn't exist you'd also see E_WARNING level error like this: `PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/various/google-api-php-client-2.1.1/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php/insert.php on line 6`. If there was a permissions issue, it would also state that. Be sure to set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` to get all error levels.

Comment: good idea @Sherif, check my updated question

Comment: I think I got it to work eventually. I used composer instead of the archive, but the mistake I was doing was that I was creating it in the root folder, instead of creating it in my project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before continue, please check if the file autoload.php exist in the specified path.

Then, you can download and use the release package, because the GitHub repository you linked is for using with composer. The release package can be found at [Google Releases](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases)

Comment: it says it does not exist, but in fact it does. I don't know why there's this error. Moreover, the zip file that I downloaded was from the link you provided and not composer.

Comment: I downloaded and tried the same archive, using you insert.php code (commenting some lines) and it works for me. You can create a simply php file in the google api folder containing echo "someting" and call a require to that file to figure out what is happening.

Comment: I think I got it to work eventually. I used composer instead of the archive, but the mistake I was doing was that I was creating it in the root folder, instead of creating it in my project folder.